# Google pie chart single value

Tags: javascript, charts, pie-chart

I am using a Google Pie Chart and have a problem modifying it. After many complicated calculations I get a percentage value, say 67%. I want that single percentage value to be shown in pie/donut chart.

My HTML code is

```
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

My Javascript code is

```
function drawChart() {
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Category', 'Value'],
    ['Foo', 67]
]);

var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, {
    height: 400,
    width: 600,
    pieHole: 0.5,
    pieSliceTextStyle: {
        color: '#000000'
    }
});
}
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart'], callback: drawChart});
```

You can have a look here http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/mx03tcx5/

How do I make the graph cover up only 67% of the pie instead of 100%, since I am only providing a single value. Is there any other way to achieve this..

Comment: Quick fix: Just create a dummy dataset with the remaining percentage. After all, it has to be 67% of something.

Comment: Hey I have been using the same trick which you have suggested. Thanks for that! But I was looking for a more concrete solution, if there is one. Anyways, thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

add this

```
slices: {
            1: { color: 'transparent', textStyle : {color:'transparent'} }
          }
```

to the same scope with pieSliceTextStyle. And 
add

```
['', 33]
```

after ['Foo', 67].

For more info you can check this : [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart)

After modification :

```
chart.draw(data, {
        height: 400,
        width: 600,
        pieHole: 0.5,
        pieSliceTextStyle: {
            color: '#000000'
        },
        slices: {
            1: { color: 'transparent', textStyle : {color:'transparent'} }
          }
    });


var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Category', 'Value'],
        ['Foo', 67],
        ['', 33]
    ]);
```

if you want to check it in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4oxbnmqr/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Also, could you also help me remove the number 67 on the shaded part and instead place it in the middle of the circle, hole. .. I tried using legend option on your fiddle, but I am not able to do so.