# What should I adjust in google charts code to get rid of some properties? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, charts

What should I change in google charts code example to get rid of all slice % and leave only % for one slice, and also the column that shows what each colour represents?

Link to google chart - https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#donut

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          ['Work',     11],
          ['Eat',      2],
          ['Commute',  2],
          ['Watch TV', 2],
          ['Sleep',    7]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'My Daily Activities',
          pieHole: 0.4,
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donutchart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="donutchart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I only want the values circled in the image below:

[image: chart image]

Comment: Sample input/output please

Comment: Do you mean how does the chart looks like? If yes I have added image above, if not please let me know and I will add.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing options to:

```
    var options = {
      title: 'My Daily Activities',
      pieHole: 0.4,
      slices: {
        2: { textStyle : {color:'transparent'} },
        3: { textStyle : {color:'transparent'} },
        4: { textStyle : {color:'transparent'} },
        5: { textStyle : {color:'transparent'} },
      }
    };
```

This will set slices 2,3,4,5 to a transparent text colour.

Adapted from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27010671/608312

Comment: I managed to get rid of the label 'legend: 'none''

but still not sure where should I add 'pieslicetext: "none"

Answer (score 0):

@JakeSteam this is the code I have so far.. I could 'make transparent' lebel for 'others' but in this case I would like to get rid of '%' so only slice keeps the value and the colour.

```
<html>
      <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="loader.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

         google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Metric', 'Score', 'Site'],
        ['Uniqueness', 6.178, 'https://www.google.com/'],
        ['', 93.82, 'https://www.bing.com/']
      ]);

      var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
      view.setColumns([0, 1]);

      var options = {
        legend: 'none',
        title: 'Unique Identifiability',
        pieHole: 0.6,
        colors: ['#EE7023', '#808080']

      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('uniqueness'));



      google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function () {
        var selection = chart.getSelection(); 


        if (selection.length > 0) {

          window.open(data.getValue(selection[0].row, 2), '_blank');
          console.log(data.getValue(selection[0].row, 2));
        }
      });
```

Comment: The code I posted answered the question you asked. If you now just want to hide the % symbol, that's a different question, so you should make a new one. If your initial question is answered, feel free to mark the question as solved!